# regular win10 updates change SerialNumber

Tags: windows, wmi, wmic, serial-number, product-key

Our software generates a unique machine fingerprint which is used in our product's licensing.

The machine fingerprint includes the `SerialNumber` obtained using `WMI` from `Win32_OperatingSystem` (e.g. `wmic os get SerialNumber`).

Lately we have had a few customers reporting a failed license check due to a `SerialNumber` change after a *regular* win10 update (**note**: *this is not an issue about updates from a previous windows 7/8/8.1 to a windows 10*).

Example:

- before update: `00000-00000-00000-ZZ938`
- after update: `0000-00000-00000-ZZ975`

Shouldn't `SerialNumber` be a value that does not change over time?

Is there any other `WMI` property that I can access and uniquely identifies the OS?

Comment: We've got the same issue. Did you already found more information why the serial number changes during Win10 updates?

Comment: I can confirm for sure Win32_OperatingSystem.SerialNumber is changing on Windows 10 anniversary update, will it change for future major updates, I don't know but it is worth relying on 'it will change'.